# Extracting Screen Coordinates (X and Y) of points shapefile in QGis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to extract screen coordinates (X and Y) from points shapefile in QGIS.
the tools available is extracting the coordinates based on earth coordinate.

to make it clearer, bellow is a simplified simulation.
so if i have a 5x5 pixel screen, if i move my map and it displays 3 points such as this:

xxxxx
x1xxx
xxx1x
1xxxx
xxxxx

*1 would be the point

when i extract the coordinates, i want to see:
(1,1), (3,2), and (0,3).

anyone has any idea how to do this?

I have tried to do so using the Vector Table from the Toolbox, and it gave me coordinates relatives to the earth, instead of my screen.

Comment: The whole point of a GIS is to convert world coordinates to screen coordinates, not the other way around. As you move the map or zoom in or out the pixel coordinate would change

Comment: Thanks for you response Ian. What you describe is exactly what i'm looking for. Zooming in and out will extract different X and Y coordinates. Moving around will also change my result. However I haven't been able to do so. I'm using the "Add X/Y fields to layer" features from the Vector Table, and the X Y i got are derived not from screen pixels.

Comment: And I'm saying that for most purposes that would be useless so no one has implemented a way to do this

Comment: yeh, i get it. I was chasing down a wrong rabbit hole, apparently. i have a point shapefile, identifying objects. i want to make training data from it. so the plan was from every display on the screen, i'd hide the points shapefile, and export the map, then i hide the map and display the points shapefile and extract the coordinates of the points that is used as my object identifier. then these two, the coordinates and the map image will be used as my training data for object recognition. thank you for your response ian. i guess i'd have to find another way to generate my training data.